How to set QuickGrid virtualized position from query string
I am using Blazor QuickGrid, bound to an ItemProvider with virtualize enabled. I would like to persist the scrolled location of the the grid to the query string, and then have the grid start at that position when linked to.
I feel persisting pagination, sort, and filter is important so that when a user clicks off the grid page, then goes back in history, they are on the same page of data (unless data has changed). I am able to persist to the query string by calling this after items get provided:
private async Task OnGridItemsProvided()
{
    var newQueryString = "state=" + JsonSerializer.Serialize(Provider.GridState);
    var fullUri = new Uri(nav.Uri);
    var baseUri = fullUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
    nav.NavigateTo($"{baseUri}?{newQueryString}");
}

And can confirm the query string updates as I scroll the grid:
data/some?state={"StartIndex":93,"Count":50}

However, I can't find any way to force the grid to go to that location from code when a user lands on that.
What I would like to do is something like:
var stateJson = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new Uri(nav.Uri).Query).Get("state");
var state = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GridState>(stateJson);

grid.Virtualization.SetStartIndex(state.Skip)

I tried using grid.Pagination.SetCurrentPageIndexAsync, but when pagination is set, the grid no longer virtualizes.

I don't think you can.  I experimented with it a while ago and in the end went with pagination and persistinng the pagination/sort state.

Is the sample what you want?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/quickgrid?view=aspnetcore-9.0&tabs=visual-studio#remote-data

https://www.fluentui-blazor.net/DataGrid I believe this now supports this however still marked experimental.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis that's what I'm landing on per https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26943

@BrianParker I looked and didn't see a way to set the scroll position.  do let  us know if you find such.

@RuikaiFeng no, that is related to how I can get the scroll index, but I don't see a way to set it.
